# Cannot produce x,y coordinates in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, geometry

ArcMap version 10.3.1
Python version 2.7.12

I'm trying to produce a points table with one row. The row should include x,y coordinates for the point and optionally a name.

I have tried this two different ways and failed, each yielding separate results.

Attempt 1:

(Creates a shapefile, but it is empty and unprojected)

temp is a variable holding '[37.00, -79.00]'

```
pointslist = []
pointslist.append(temp)

pt = arcpy.Point()
ptGeoms = []
for p in pointslist:
    pt.X = p[0]
    pt.Y = p[1]
    ptGeoms.append(arcpy.PointGeometry(pt))

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ptGeoms, r"C:\Temp\test.shp")
```

Attempt 2:

(Always results in the name field being populated, but the x,y remaining null)

```
fc = "p:/435final/standin.gdb/userx"
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@XY"])
xy = (39.55, -79.00)
cursor.insertRow(["USER", xy])
del cursor
```

Comment: Yes. I have tried addressing the fields as "SHAPE@XY" as well as individually.

Comment: i copied your attempt one and ran t - it worked for me

Comment: also if its just one coordinate you dont need to loop through it

Comment: Thank you for letting me know it worked for you. I'll talk to my professor in the morning!

Comment: it showed up in Antarctica for me though, you have define the spatial reference. where is this supposed to be?

Comment: Your second attempt didn't specify the attribute column to accept "User" and should have reported an error (which you didn't provide).  There's four or five other fundamental errors too.  You did at least use the correct (DA) cursor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things:

1. In your first attempt you have a for loop.  You do not need to loop through the points list because you only have one coordinate. You can just pass your coordinate values through the arcpy geometries
2. I ran your code and my point showed up somewhere in Antarctica. So I ran it again and switched your x,y positions and the point showed up in Virginia
3. Your point needs to be in a coordinate system when creating it because arcmap will tell you that it cannot be drawn without a coordinate system.

Here is what I have assuming you want your point in Virginia and not somewhere on a Antarctic iceberg

```
point  = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(-79.00,37.00),arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(point, r"path\noury.shp")
```

Comment: Thank you for an informative and well formatted answer. I ended up solving this problem by exporting the coordinates into a text file. I then imported them into ArcMap, using the "MakeXYEventLayer_management"  feature. Not ideal, but it got me though.